# Reducing the cyclomatic complexity with getters and setters, from multiples POJOS

Tags: java, spring, if-statement, cyclomatic-complexity

this question is for Spring java. I have a problem with the bunches of If statements: 
Actually I have two pojos in a service layer.

I get the field from one pojo. If this field contains info, I'll set the response to the other pojom passing through an especific decrypt method.

Original Example:

```
if (clReq.getIdCliente() != null && clReq.getIdCliente().trim().equals("")) {

entity.setFiId(Integer.valueOf(RijndaelCrypto.decrypt(clReq.getIdCliente(), IV, this.privateKey)));

} else {

throw new ClientesBOException("3-FALTA DATOS REQUERIDOS-ERROR");
}
```

Example 2: I reduce the main condition in an external method:

```
if (validaCha(clReq.getIdCliente())) {
entity.setFiId(Integer.valueOf(RijndaelCrypto.decrypt(clReq.getIdCliente(), IV, this.privateKey)));         
}
```

External Method:

```
public static final boolean validaCha(String val) throws ClientesBOException {  
    if(StringUtils.isBlank(val)) {
       throw new ClientesBOException("ERROR!, Mandatory data missing");    
    }     
    return true;     
  }
```

The main problem!! The pojo contains 30 fields. I must validate each field, because the Decryption. Now I have this 30 times, with different attributes.

```
     if (validaCha(clReq.getIdCliente())) {      
 entity.setFiId(Integer.valueOf(RijndaelCrypto.decrypt(clReq.getIdCliente(), IV, this.privateKey)));         
          }
```

I´m looking for help.
I read about make the condition inside set methods from entity pojo. 
Use Map. 
Use patterns. 
Finally I dont find the light

Thanks!!!!!!

Comment: Is a field valid if it has a non-blank (not null and not empty) string value? How do these values get populated -- through reflection or setter invocations?

Comment: The tables contains NULL and  NOT NULL values. This method is a POST